# How to show progress bar when loading datagridview (using Task.Run)?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, datagridview, progress-bar

```
private void btnLoad_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                string filename = txtfile.Text;
                progressBar.Visible = true;
                progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;

                DataTable dt= GetDt(filename);           
                datagridview1.DataSource = dt;           
                datagridview1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;     

                progressBar.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

On button click I am trying to display a progress bar, do the load (takes about 10 seconds), AutoSizeRowsMode that takes about 5 seconds, and then hide the progress bar. However, while the load is happening, I cannot see the progress bar - it looks like the app has frozen. Is this because everything runs on single thread?

To counter this possible problem, I tried to put the grid load into separate thread using Task.Run:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
                {    
                    DataTable dt= GetDt(filename);           
                    datagridview1.DataSource = dt;         
                    datagridview1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;              
                });
```

Above code gives error because the datagridview is on UI thread where as the Task.Run is on separate thread. What is the simples solution here?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping UI object calls with [Dispatcher.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: @JohnDoe, this is a WinForms app.

Comment: Getting the data could be done on a background thread but loading the data into the grid and then auto-sizing rows must be done on the UI thread, so the UI thread is not able to update any progress indicators. Setting those two grid properties are both atomic operations. You could update progress in between but that's all. There's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: OK so there is no way to show a progress bar when autosizing?

Comment: Consider [Implementing Virtual Mode in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is wpf or winforms but you can use the Progress class for this it synchronizes with the base context where it is initialized. So it will have no issues communicating with the Main/UI thread.

[Progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Progress_1__ctor_System_Action__0__) can be initialized with an Action and this action can be really helpful in updating your UI components.

basic click event example tested on WPF forms:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IProgress<int> p = new Progress<int>((x)=>
            {
                pg1.Value = x;
                if (x == 100)
                {
                   //update data grid here
                   MessageBox.Show("Completed!");                   
                }                
            });
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //Your heavy tasks can go here 
                var x = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    x += 10;
                    p.Report(x); //report back progress 
                }
            });
        }
```

Here pg1 (Progress bar component of WPF) is updated on button click event which triggers the heavy process you need in the new task run.

Updated code where the grid data loading can be done.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of having to update the datagridview on the UI thread

Comment: @asaf92 That is easy we can do the grid update inside the action delegate, did not realize the last statement thanks for pointing out! Updated code as well.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed the thing with the progress being updated on the UI thread because of how `Progress` is being initialized. Interesting! I didn't know that.

Comment: However, I think it's better to update the grid after the calculation is complete and not during the progress-update, so perhaps make this function `async void`, `await` the `Task` and update the `DataSource` when done?

Answer (score 0):

See if [the following](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/windows-forms-csharp/tree/Version1/LoadDataGridViewProgressBar) will fulfill your basic requirements.

The Progressbar is on a panel which once done loading is hidden, alternate is to show a child form with a progressbar and close once data is loaded.

- Data is read from a SQL-Server [database](https://gist.github.com/karenpayneoregon/c3361a4d4503c8851dcb43f8d6b2526f)
- Using a separate [class](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/windows-forms-csharp/blob/Version1/LoadDataGridViewProgressBar/Classes/Operations.cs)

Code responsible to load data

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LoadDataGridViewProgressBar.Classes
{
    public class Operations
    {

        private static string _connectionString = 
            "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=NorthWind2020;Integrated Security=True";

        public static async Task<(Exception exception, DataTable dataTable)> LoadCustomerData()
        {

            var customersDataTable = new DataTable();

            using (var cn = new SqlConnection() { ConnectionString = _connectionString })
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand() { Connection = cn })
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText =
                            "SELECT  C.CustomerIdentifier, C.CompanyName, C.ContactId, CT.ContactTitle, C.City, CO.[Name] " + 
                            "FROM Customers AS C INNER JOIN ContactType AS CT ON C.ContactTypeIdentifier = CT.ContactTypeIdentifier " + 
                            "INNER JOIN Countries AS CO ON C.CountryIdentifier = CO.CountryIdentifier ";

        
                        await cn.OpenAsync();

                        customersDataTable.Load(await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync());

                        customersDataTable.Columns["Name"].AllowDBNull = false;
                        customersDataTable.Columns["CustomerIdentifier"].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;
                        customersDataTable.Columns["ContactId"].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;


                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        return (exception, customersDataTable);
                    }
                }
            }

            return (null, customersDataTable);

        }
    }
}
```

In the form I use a BindingSource for working with data which is used as the DataSource for the DataGridView.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using LoadDataGridViewProgressBar.Classes;

namespace LoadDataGridViewProgressBar
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public readonly BindingSource _customersBindingSource = new BindingSource();
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            Shown += OnShown;
            
        }

        private async void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var (exception, dataTable) = await Operations.LoadCustomerData();
            
            try
            {
                if (exception == null)
                {
                    _customersBindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;
                    customerDataGridView.DataSource = _customersBindingSource;
                    customerDataGridView.ExpandColumns(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    CurrentButton.Enabled = false;
                    MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
                progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
                panel1.Hide();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
            progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 30;
        }

        private void CurrentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_customersBindingSource.Current == null) return;
            
            // access fields from the DataRow
            var data = ((DataRowView) _customersBindingSource.Current).Row;

            MessageBox.Show($"{data.Field<int>("CustomerIdentifier")}");
        }
    }
}
```

Resize DataGridView columns

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LoadDataGridViewProgressBar.Classes
{
    public static class DataGridViewExtensions
    {
        public static void ExpandColumns(this DataGridView sender, bool sizable = false)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in sender.Columns)
            {
                // ensure we are not attempting to do this on a Entity
                if (col.ValueType.Name != "ICollection`1")
                {
                    col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
                }
            }

            if (!sizable) return;

            for (int index = 0; index <= sender.Columns.Count - 1; index++)
            {
                int columnWidth = sender.Columns[index].Width;

                sender.Columns[index].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;

                // Set Width to calculated AutoSize value:
                sender.Columns[index].Width = columnWidth;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

> I cannot see the progress bar - it looks like the app has frozen. Is
> this because everything runs on single thread?

Correct

> Above code gives error because the datagridview is on UI thread where
> as the Task.Run is on separate thread.

Also correct

> What is the simples solution here?

The simplest solution would be to use MVVM architecture and bind the `DataSource` property to an `ObservableCollection` in the view-model, but if we ignore that, the most straight-forward way would be to `GetDt` on a worker thread (using `Task.Run`), but to set the `DataSource` on the UI thread.

So instead of this:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    DataTable dt= GetDt(filename);
    datagridview1.DataSource = dt;
    datagridview1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;
});
```

Do this:

```
DataTable dt = await Task.Run(() => GetDt(filename));
datagridview1.DataSource = dt;
datagridview1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;
```

Comment: I want to have the following line in separate task and show progress bar as it takes anywhere between 5 to 20 seconds to run `datagridview1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;`

Comment: This is a different problem, but in regards to progress-bar updates this is your solution. You can update the progress from inside `GetDt` and the UI thread will show it

Comment: Or even simpler: `DataTable dt = await Task.Run(() => GetDt(filename));`

Comment: @IteratioN7T I didn't ask the user to migrate anything to MVVM and my solution doesn't require MVVM. I left the MVVM comment as a side note. Did you actually read the code? There's no binding anywhere and we're setting the `DataSource` in code.